# "On the header" vs. "in the header"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

> Include logo on the header of all the pages.

In that sentence, is it correct to use *on* or should it be *in*?

I have a decent idea of where to use *on* and *in* most of the time. But in the above sentence, both seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In the header" sounds a little better to me.

When it comes to text and graphical elements *in* a document, there seems to be a subtle difference between "in" and "on." "On" is more literal and specific. It makes me think of something actually being on the surface of the page. "In," on the other hand, seems to be slightly more abstract, and is applicable to more cases.

I suppose it depends on how you think of a header. Is it an abstract, conceptual unit like a paragraph? Or is it a part of the physical page? I think it is more like a paragraph, especially from the point of view of the person creating the document.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is meant by "header":

"Include logo in [the contents of] the header" if the header material is to include a logo.

Or, "place logo on [or:as] the header" if all there is to the header is a logo.

Comment: There is "the head" of the page, and there is "the header" to the page. The first means the top of the page; the second the material appearing at the head of each page.

Comment: It's the second one. Like in a word document, we add a header and footer. It's that header.